# Trouble with aggregate in Where clause, Selecting Max(x) When Max(x) != 3

Tags: sql

I am trying to reconfigure the below sql to only pull records when the Max(Field) != 3 but keep getting an error (detailed) below.

This is the code before adding the Where Max(field) != 3

```
SELECT P.Code,
    MAX(PW.v1) AS V1
FROM SW
INNER JOIN S ON SW.S_Id = S.Id
INNER JOIN PW ON SW.PW_Id = PW.Id
INNER JOIN PON S.P_Id = P.id
WHERE S.P_Id = P.id
GROUP BY P.Code
```

My Attempt

```
SELECT P.Code,
    MAX(PW.v1) AS V1
FROM SW
INNER JOIN S ON SW.S_Id = S.Id
INNER JOIN PW ON SW.PW_Id = PW.Id
INNER JOIN PON S.P_Id = P.id
WHERE S.P_Id = P.id
AND (SELECT MAX(PW.v1)
     FROM SW AS SW2
     WHERE SW.PWId = SW2.PW_Id) != 3
GROUP BY P.Code
```

This is the error I get and not sure what to do:
*An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.*

Comment: Instead of adding the sub-query in the `WHERE`, have you tried adding `HAVING MAX(PW.v1) != 3` ?

Comment: Try this instead:
    SELECT P.Code,
    MAX(PW.v1) AS V1
    FROM SW
    INNER JOIN S ON SW.S_Id = S.Id
    INNER JOIN PW ON SW.PW_Id = PW.Id
    INNER JOIN PON S.P_Id = P.id
    WHERE S.P_Id = P.id
    GROUP BY P.Code
    HAVING (SELECT MAX(PW.v1)
    WHERE SW.PWId = SW2.PW_Id) != 3

Comment: The problem is your sub select is selecting the max of PW, but PW is not part of the resultset of your subselect.  You need to add the join into your subselect as well. That said, it sounds like you'd be better of using a `Having` clause per @vlumi

Comment: Thank you all, using the Having worked great. Most appreciated for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional method of filtering on results of an aggregate can be achieved by using HAVING clause. I also removed the unnecessary WHERE clause as you already joined those 2 tables on that column. Here is the query:

```
SELECT P.Code
       ,MAX(PW.v1) AS V1
FROM SW
     INNER JOIN S 
        ON SW.S_Id = S.Id
     INNER JOIN PW 
        ON SW.PW_Id = PW.Id
     INNER JOIN P 
        ON S.P_Id = P.id
GROUP BY P.Code
HAVING MAX(PW.v1)!=3;
```